# SQL left outer join table

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I'm trying to pull out 3 columns from two tables, and I seem to be having a little problem.

```
SELECT a.[CreatedFromIp], b.[Token],  b.[MaskedP]
from [dbo].[Users] a LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Cards] b ON a.[Id]= b.[Id]
WHERE CreatedFromIp IS NOT NULL
Order by Token
```

but I keep getting Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

If I turn the tables around, I get all the token and masked info, but the IP result is just a whole list of NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your both table id column to `bigint` - due to data type mismatch you are getting the error

```
SELECT a.[CreatedFromIp], b.[Token],  b.[MaskedP]
from [dbo].[Users] a LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Cards] b 
ON cast(a.[Id] as bigint)= cast(b.[Id] as bigint)
WHERE CreatedFromIp IS NOT NULL
Order by Token
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but its a work table and when I try and change it I get an "Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint." as I dont have the admin rights to do so.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server automatically converts *away* from strings when there is a comparison.  The simple solution is to require that all columns that might be used in a `join` are of the same type.  In this case, a simple `foreign key` definition would have helped when setting up the data model.

You can remove the error by converting to strings:

```
SELECT u.[CreatedFromIp], c.[Token], c.[MaskedP]
FROM [dbo].[Users] u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     [dbo].[Cards] c
      ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), u.[Id]) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), c.[Id])
WHERE CreatedFromIp IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Token;
```

Of course, one of those type conversions is redundant, because the field is already a string.

Alternatively, you can convert the columns to integers -- using `try_convert()` or `try_cast()`:

```
SELECT u.[CreatedFromIp], c.[Token], c.[MaskedP]
FROM [dbo].[Users] u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     [dbo].[Cards] c
      ON TRY_CONVERT(int, u.[Id]) = TRY_CONVERT(int, c.[Id])
WHERE CreatedFromIp IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Token;
```

Of course, the real solution is to fix the data model so the columns used in the `JOIN`s have the same type.